# SQL to Hive query conversion

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera

I have an sql query as below. I want to convert this to hive query, is this possible? Using cloudera/hadoop. Thanks

```
DECLARE
@sd_y FLOAT, 
@sd_x1 FLOAT,
@sd_x2 FLOAT,
SELECT
@sd_y = SUM(Y_w*Y),
@sd_x1 = SUM(Y_w*X1),
@sd_x2 = SUM(Y_w*X2)
FROM dbo.c
UPDATE dbo.c
SET
Y = SQRT(Y_w)*(Y-@sd_y),
X1 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X1-@sd_x1),
X2 = SQRT(Y_w)*(X2-@sd_x2)
SELECT
@sd_y,
@sd_x1,
@sd_x2
```

Comment: My recommendation is to create a new table.  Hive isn't really designed to do updates to an existing table.

Comment: **This is not a SQL query**. This is a **Transact-SQL script** which merges SQL with procedural programming. With Hive, you would need a Java program + JDBC to mimic that. Plus, as Gordon already stated, Hive was not designed for UPDATEs. Really not.